# Complexity in implementing Predictive Intelligence?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are a relatively new SFMC partner in Asia. We are told that Predictive Intelligence implementation is very tricky that it has to be done by SFMC Internal Service team. Is it true? Where is the best resource to get tutorial on the steps to implement PI? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the SFMC folks could chime in, but as far as I know, it's an integration behind the scenes... so there's no front-end for doing the provisioning.  Plus, there's quite a bit of data discovery required to build the product, category, etc., schemas.

Same thing goes for Audience Builder, but I've heard they're working on a front-end for provisioning.